# Swift UISegmentedControl if change

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

**How can I create check all time when UISegmentedControl was cheged to another case ?**

Example

I create UISegmentedControl:

```
var type = 0

 @objc func change(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
      case 0:
        type = 0
      case 1:
        type = 1
      case 2:
        type = 2
      case 3:
        type = 3
      default:
        type = 2
    }
```

And I have func when I need to check and change data when change button in 
SegmentedControl

```
func Example() {

  if type == 0 {
    print("case 0")
  } else if type == 1 {
    print("case 1")
  } else if type == 2 {
    print("case 2")
  } else if type == 3 {
    print("case 3")
  }
}
```

Comment: I think one curlybrase missing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't check by calling a function. Move the code to be executed after the type changes into the action

```
@objc func change(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
     switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
     case 0:
         type = 0
         print("case 0")
     case 1:
         type = 1
         print("case 1")
     case 3:
         type = 3
         print("case 3")
     default:
         type = 2
         print("case 2")
    }
}
```

```
func Example() {
    if type == 0 {
       print("case 0")
    } else if type == 1 {
       print("case 1")
    } else if type == 2 {
       print("case 2")
    } else if type == 3 {
       print("case 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me with another question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025264/swift-mapbox-change-points-if-change-segmentedcontrol

Comment: I'm not familiar with `MapBox` but the error message `Source mapPoints already exists` seems to be quite meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simplifying your problem to this :

```
@objc func change(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    print("case \(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    // do whatever you need with sender.selectedSegmentIndex here directly   
}
```